# JTabbedPane's tabs overlap

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

I got a simple Swing application that consists of a JFrame, JMenuBar, and two JPanel's and I can't add properly a JTabbedPane to one of the JPanels. Tabs of the JTabbedPane overlap and are located in a weird spot. Thats how it looks at the moment:
[image: Overlapping tabs]

Here's how I create the GUI:

```
Toolkit tk=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
int MAIN_FRAME_WIDTH = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
int MAIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
applicationFrame=new JFrame();
applicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
applicationFrame.setBounds(0, 0, MAIN_FRAME_WIDTH, MAIN_FRAME_HEIGHT);
applicationFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
ToolbarPanel toolbar=new ToolbarPanel(iLineColorButtonController);//my custom JPanel
applicationFrame.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
PanelWithTabs panelWithTabs=new PanelWithTabs();//custom panel with JTabbedPane
applicationFrame.add(panelWithTabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);
applicationFrame.setVisible(true);
```

The PanelWithTabs class:

```
public PanelWithTabs() {
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane=new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", new JPanel());
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", new JPanel());
    add(tabbedPane);
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: 1. call `applicationFrame.setVisible(true)` only after the frame is otherwise ready. 2. call `applicationFrame.pack()` before that. (3. unrelated, but you can use [Frame.setExtendedState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29) for maximization).

Comment: I think it's because`panelWithTabs`'s layout is a `FlowLayout`. Change it to something like `BorderLayout` or simply make `PanelWithTabs` extend `JTabbedPane` and remove the `JTabbedPane` instance in the cunstructor.

Comment: @LuxxMiner Thank you, both your solutions work fine :)

Comment: @kiheru yeah, I forgot to paste the applicationFrame.setVisible(true) line, thanks for advices :)

Comment: Frame.setExtendedState is actually a much better choice, because it won't overlap whatever taskbar and/or system menu bar may be present.  And it will properly handle a desktop that spans multiple monitors.

Comment: Set the layout manager for `PanelWithTabs` to something like `BorderLayout` BEFORE you add the `tabbedPane`